# javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf

I have two input fields say val1 and val2 in jsp.Let say val1 is dynamic, I need to restrict user entering the value of val2 not exceeding val1. It can be equal but not more. I tried with onKeypress but i was not able to success. Val1 value can be get from document.getElementById(..).value. Can anyone tell me the efficient way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`onChange`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/evhan_onchange.html) event.

```
<script>
function checkValues(in) {
    var val1 = getElementById(val1);
    var val2 = getElementById(val2);

    // Don't check if values are missing
    if (val1.value == "" || val2.value == "") return;

    // Don't allow val2 to be greater than val1
    if (parseInt(val1.value) 
            > parseInt(val2.value)) {
        // Try not to use an alert, replace this with an in-page warning.
        alert("Value 2 must be greater than Value 1.");
        in.value = "";
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="val1" onChange="checkValues(this)" />
<input type="text" id="val2" onChange="checkValues(this)" />
```

Note that this doesn't fully stop a user from submitting an invalid value. You should also verify the values on the server

Comment: So that means , there no way in javaScript to restrict the user so that the user cannot enter greater val2 than val1.

Comment: Exactly. If a user turns off javascript, they can enter any value they want.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this in client side javascript.

```
if (document.getElementById('val1').value.length <= document.getElementById('val2').value.length)
```

Comment: Comparing the length isn't what he's looking for `7` is greater than `3`, but your solution allows that.

Comment: Oh I see, must have misread... Bit harsh voting me down there somebody :-)

Comment: Didn't vote down. I chose to comment instead. Sorry if my comment caused you to get voted down :|